# Discrepancies in the "totalsForAllResults" field for "ga:users"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

If I make a request to the Google Analytics API using only the metric "ga:users", the result is different to the one that is returned in the "totalsForAllResult" field when I add a dimension.

Does anyone know the explanation for this and which is the correct result?

Comment: is the request sampled?

Comment: No, the field "containsSampledData" is false in the response.

Comment: Which dimension are you taking? Can you show the screenshot of output?

Comment: This happens when several dimensions, but here it is an example with and without "Operating System" dimension.

With the dimension: "totalsForAllResults"=>{"ga:users"=>"60585"} and 
without the dimension: "totalsForAllResults"=>{"ga:users"=>"60675"}. 

The request is exactly the same, I just removed the dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sum up the user counts per dimension and get a gross total as one and the same user can appear in multiple dimension values. For a detailed explanation look [here](https://help.analyticsedge.com/article/misunderstood-metrics-users/). If you want to get the total users value, repeat the API request w/o the dimension. Apparently, Google does the mistake of blindly summing the values themselves in the `totalsForAllResults` field of the [response of the Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#data_response) which can be highly misleading.